# Multiple output jar files for intellij pom.xml file

Tags: java, build

Is it possible to build 2 of the same jar files but in separate directories in intellij?
[image]

As you can see in lines 41 and 42 I have the outputFile locations set to 2 different locations, however it only builds the jar file in the last outputFile. Is it possible to build in 2 different directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible, just define another execution section and put your second output file path there like described here [Maven Shade Plugin to produce two Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845423/maven-shade-plugin-to-produce-two-jars)

You may have to define separate ids for both executions.